# Java - Reflection - How to get @RequestHeader value using reflection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection, spring-annotations, request-headers

Following is my method :

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition()...");
        for (int i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            CreateRequisitionRO requisitionRequest = request[i];

            // FIXME this has to be removed/moved
            requisitionRequest.setFundManager(requisitionRequest.getUserId());
            // FIXME might have to search using param level as well
            SystemDefault sysDefault = dbFuncs.references.systemDefault
                    .findByCompanyAndDivisionAndPortfolio(
                            userContext.getCompany(),
                            userContext.getDivision(),
                            requisitionRequest.getPortfolio());
            requisitionRequest.setCustodianN(sysDefault.getCustodianN());

            gateKeeper.route(requisitionRequest);
        }
    }
```

In which I am able to get the following details

```
1. @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
2. void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
                @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly)
 (in thesecond one i am able to get the argument type like boolean etc)
```

I get the above details like the following :

```
Class cls;
cls = Class.forName(obj.getName());
Method[] method = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method2 : method) {
     RequestMapping requestMappingAnnotation =   method2.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);       // gets the method which is maped with   RequestMapping Annotation
     requestMappingValues = requestMappingAnnotation.value(); // to get the url value
      RequestMethod[] methods = requestMappingAnnotation.method(); // to get the request   method type
      requestingMethod = methods[0].name();
}
```

In the same way when I try to get `@RequestHeader` like the following I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

below is the code snippet I used

```
RequestHeader requestHeader = method2.getAnnotation(RequestHeader.class);
System.out.println("requestHeader : "+requestHeader.value());
```

what I am trying to get is `@RequestHeader("validateOnly")` the value this annotations contains.

EDIT :

Thanks to @NilsH who always support for all the clarifications asked even if it required time to be spent :

this is how i solved it `but the information will be available if the program is in debug mode`

i have used spring to do this :

```
LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer lcl = new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer();
                                parametersDefinedForMethod = lcl.getParameterNames(method2);
                                for (String params : parametersDefinedForMethod) {
                                    System.out.println("Params : "+params);
                                }
```

Please help me to get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RequestHeader` is a parameter level annotation in this case. Try using [`Method.getParameterAnnotations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations%28%29) to get it.

**Edit**

An example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void someMethodWithParamAnnotations(String s, @MyAnnotation String s2) {

    }
}
```

And then somewhere else

```
Method m = MyClass.class.getMethod("someMethodWithParamAnnotations", String.class, String.class);
Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = m.getParameterAnnotations();
Annotation[] firstParamAnnotation = paramAnnotations[0]; 
// Above is empty array, since first parameter has no annotation

Annotation[] secondParamAnnotation = paramAnnotations[1]; 
// Above contains an array with the `@MyAnnotation` annotation
```

Comment: Thanks NilsH, would you give some code snippet to start with, Please?

Comment: @Anto I have added an example you should be able to adapt to your application.

Comment: +1 for the detailed post NilsH :). I am trying your method now, will mark it once it is done so that it will help others too.

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT, i have solved it using spring it is so simple. hope it helps others too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NilsH who always support for all the clarifications asked even if it required time to be spent :

this is how i solved it but the information will be available if the program is in debug mode

i have used spring to do this :

```
LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer lcl = 
    new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer();
parametersDefinedForMethod = lcl.getParameterNames(method2);
for (String params : parametersDefinedForMethod) {
    System.out.println("Params : "+params);
}
```

Comment: i have posted here as answer thinking that this may help others too. :)